# Subpages in jQuery Mobile | Navigation in listview

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

may someone explain to me, how the subpages functionality is working in jQuery Mobile?

I read the [docs of the navmodel](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html), but still no idea.

What I want to reach is to make a paging nav for a listview. It all worked fine so far when using Ajax ($.get(...)), but than the back button is not functioning correctly.

May some make a small example how this can be achieved with jQuery Mobile's subpages?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I can't add a JSFiddle, because the main part of the code is doing a simple ajax request and loads a HTML snippet from the server.

```js
var loadListview = function(page) {
        var $listview = $('#listview');
        $.get('page/loadListview', {
                p: page
        }, function(response) {
                $listview.html(response).trigger('create').find('.navbar a').bind('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var page = $(this).data('navbar-page');
                        loadListview(page);
                });
        });
};
```

I've also tried to use the following to manipulate the navigation.

```js
window.history.pushState({ navBarPage: page }, '','page/listview?p='+page);
```

but it is in a conflict with jquery mobile.

There must be a smarter way with subpages.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? A JSfiddle would be much appreciated.